# UITableview with variable row height crashes on reorder

Tags: iphone, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

There seems to be a `UITableView` bug, simple `UITableView` is created and the editing mode is set to be YES, all rows have varying height. For example,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
        return 58;
    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
        return 520;
    else
        return 100;
}
```

Now on touching reorder control of second row application crashes.
Perhaps these row heights enforce the `UITableView` to auto scroll an invisible `UITableViewCell` from the bottom, but `UITableView` should have handled it.

Any idea….

Comment: What code have you used for reordering of rows?

Comment: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{

    Item *item = [self.itemArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.itemArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.itemArray insertObject:item atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exchange it..not remove and re-insert it..

```
[self.itemArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndex
                                 withObjectAtIndex:targetIndex];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Even if the body of of method `moveRowAtIndexPath` is empty, application crashes. But if all cells have same size then no crash will occur.

Comment: Then there must be some problem with your array count.check it!

Comment: there is no problem in array.count.